# Activatig primefaces' datatable row expansion without the row toggler

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a functional requirement to expand a row in a p:dataTable through a JSF2 commandButton. Basically, I need my button to do what the row toggler does. I assume it would be something like this:

```
<p:commandButton ... onclick="the function called by the toggler" ... />
```

My javascript is really not there for figuring out which function does it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I asked the same question on the primefaces forum. This is the direction to go: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11308&p=55114#p55114.